# Angular multiple cascade Select Option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular

I am implement multiple cascade select option. For example, I have three objects, `Country`,`City`,`School`. They are many-to-many-to-many relationship. I want to have three DropDwon(select options). When I select Country, the City will show only in the country, and if then select City, Only the school in this city will show. I try to bind the onSelectChange event, But it output undefined for passing model.
Here is my current code.

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
   <select required class="form-control" id="CountryId" name="CountryId" [(ngModel)]="model.CountryId"  (ngModelChange)="OnSelectChange(model.CountryId)" >
     <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="model.CountryId">{{model.Country}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `$event.target.value` from DOM to your typescript. Please try that and see if its working.

```
<div class="col-xs-9">
<select required class="form-control" id="CountryId" name="CountryId" [(ngModel)]="model.CountryId"  (ngModelChange)="OnSelectChange($event.target.value)" >
 <option *ngFor="let country of countries" [value]="model.CountryId">{{model.Country}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```